# Cómo NO dejar seleccionar otro formulario hasta completar el abierto

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Supongamos que abro un formulario que permite buscar un producto en la base de datos, pero no quiero que se minimice o que el usuario seleccione otro formulario de la aplicación hasta que se complete o cierre el actual, algo así como lo que pasa con los Messagebox, que al cliquear algún form del programa avisa que se atienda ese primero para poder continuar.

Comment: `form.ShowDialog()` puede ayudar a este fin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Form tiene un método ShowDialog que muestra el formulario como una ventana modal, de forma que no puedes ir a otra ventana de la aplicación hasta que cierres ésta. ([Form.ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx))

Lo que no evitará es que puedas ir a otra aplicación.

Para evitar que se pueda minimizar la ventana puedes deshabilitar el botón de minimizar estableciendo la propiedad MinimizeBox a false:

```
            var f = new Form1
        {
            MinimizeBox = false
        };
        f.ShowDialog();
```

También podrías ocultar todos los botones (minimizar, maximizar y cerrar) estableciendo la propiedad ControlBox a false:

```
            var f = new Form1
        {
            ControlBox = false
        };
        f.ShowDialog();
```

Más información:

[Cómo: Mostrar formularios Windows Forms modales y no modales](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/39wcs2dh(v=vs.110).aspx)